# EF Core equivalent to SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am currently trying to migrate into EF Core & I'm trying to figure out the SQL Generator equivalent.

I'm used to:

- Defining the SQL Generator code in a common library
- Plugging-in the SQL Generator instance through the DbConfiguration

Of course, the `DbConfiguration` file is gone now in-favor of calling `OnConfiguring` in the concrete `DbContext`.

The problem is: I can't seem to find good information on how to implement a default SQL Generator?

- What is the EF CORE equivalent here?
- Can someone help me out please?

PREVIOUS MIGRATION EXAMPLE

For example, in standard Entity Framework (EF), I would do the following:

```
    // Applies the SqlGenerator
    internal sealed class WorkflowComponentDbConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WorkflowComponentDbContext>
    {
        public WorkflowComponentDbConfiguration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new StandardAuditSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());
        }
    }
    
   // Defines the SqlGenerator
    public class StandardAuditSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
    {
        protected override void Generate(AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation)
        {
            ConfigureAuditColumns(addColumnOperation.Column);
    
            base.Generate(addColumnOperation);
        }
    
        protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
        {
            // Do not generate a Table for a View Entity
            if (createTableOperation.Annotations.ContainsKey(typeof(IsDatabaseViewEntity).Name))
                return;
    
            ConfigureAuditColumns(createTableOperation.Columns);
    
            base.Generate(createTableOperation);
        }
    
        protected virtual void ConfigureAuditColumns(IEnumerable<ColumnModel> columns)
        {
            foreach (var columnModel in columns)
            {
                ConfigureAuditColumns(columnModel);
            }
        }
    
        protected virtual void ConfigureAuditColumns(PropertyModel column)
        {
            if (column.Name == "CreatedDateTime")
                column.DefaultValueSql = "GETUTCDATE()";
    
            if (column.Name == "UpdatedDateTime")
                column.DefaultValueSql = "GETUTCDATE()";
        } 
    }
```

Comment: So you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#default-values but for all columns with those names? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/bulk-configuration

Comment: @JeremyLakeman In (standard) EF, the SqlGenerator would auto-configure DEFAULT VALUE for mapped properties.  This would execute as the migration is being generated. In this manner...I would not have to do so manually in (say) the DbMigration.Up or EntityTypeConfiguration. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: In EF Core, the default sql is tracked as a property of the model. Migrations are built by comparing snapshots of the model, which then results in the migration steps & sql. While there probably are ways to modify the generated sql, that's something you shouldn't need to do. So as above, you want to define the default in the model, in bulk across types.

Comment: Yes, and as per the 2nd link above, you can write a loop in `OnModelCreating` to locate those properties and add the sql. My point is that since the ef core `IModel` tracks the default sql, you don't need to manually modify the migration itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I explain what I did, I want to explain why I chose a custom solution.

**Why not use a Converter Class?**
I am applying database changes across an all entities that inherit a base-class.  Most Converter examples assume I am trying to convert a Property-Type to some other Type.  And I'm not doing that.  I'm not converting anything to-and-fro.

**Why are you creating an Extension Method for this?**
All the methods I tried expected a `Entity<T>` implementation.  I want to paint vales across all entities that implement a given interface.

Lastly...other potential "avenues" were (stupidly) WAY over-complicated for what I was trying to achieve.

NOTE: if someone has a SIMPLE way to do this w/o the Extension Method I'm interested

**THE SOLUTION:**
Here is the approach...

1. Create the `IGlobalEntityConfiguration` interface (see below)
2. Create a concrete configuration class for each Assignable Interface that can be "globally" configured (I have many...below you will see 2)
3. Create an extension on Modelbuilder that accepts instances of `IGlobalEntityConfiguration`
4. Apply the concrete `IGlobalEntityConfiguration` in the DbContexts `OnModelCreating`

**THE SOLUTION CODE:**
Here is what I did...

```
/// <summary>Entity configuration across an Assignable Type</summary>
public interface IGlobalEntityConfiguration
{
    #region <Methods>

    void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder);

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>Entity configuration across an Assignable Type</summary>
public class AuditableExecutedByUserIdGlobalConfiguration : IGlobalEntityConfiguration
{
    #region <Methods>

    public virtual void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (typeof(IAuditableExecutedByUserId).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
            {
                // PROPERTIES
                var executedDateTime = builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                                              .Metadata
                                              .FindProperty("ExecutedDateTime");

                // Defaults
                if (executedDateTime != null)
                    executedDateTime.SetDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");

            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
            
/// <summary>Entity configuration across an Assignable Type</summary>
public class AuditableStandardUserNameGlobalConfiguration : IGlobalEntityConfiguration
{
    #region <Methods>

    public virtual void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (typeof(IAuditableStandardUserName).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
            {
                // PROPERTIES
                var createdDateTime = builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                                             .Metadata
                                             .FindProperty("CreatedDateTime");

                var createdByUserName = builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                                             .Metadata
                                             .FindProperty("CreatedByUserName");

                var updatedDateTime = builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                                             .Metadata
                                             .FindProperty("UpdatedDateTime");

                var updatedByUserName = builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                                             .Metadata
                                             .FindProperty("UpdatedByUserName");

                // Defaults
                if (createdDateTime != null)
                    createdDateTime.SetDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");

                if (createdByUserName != null)
                    createdByUserName.SetMaxLength(50);

                if (updatedDateTime != null)
                    updatedDateTime.SetDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");

                if (updatedByUserName != null)
                    updatedByUserName.SetMaxLength(50);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

// This is in your Concrete DbContext class
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // GLOBAL Configurations
    builder.ApplyGlobalEntityConfiguration(new AuditableStandardUserNameGlobalConfiguration());

    // ENTITY Configurations
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContextTypeConfiguration());
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ObjectStateConfiguration());
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ObjectStateEventConfiguration());
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new WorkflowConfiguration());
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new WorkflowEventConfiguration());
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new WorkflowTransitionConfiguration());
}
```

**CODE USAGE:**
Remember, the "time savings" are in the form of the configuration I didn't have to write because it is automatically-applied (for me)...

```
/// <summary>A common entity class</summary>
public class StandardIdentifiableEntity : IdentifiableEntity, IAuditableStandardUserName
{
    #region <Properties>

    public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

    public string UpdatedByUserName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedDateTime { get; set; } 

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>Workflow Provider entity</summary>
public class Workflow : StandardIdentifiableEntity
{
    #region <Properties>

    public long ContextTypeId { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public short? Order { get; set; }

    public virtual ContextType ContextType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ObjectState> ObjectStates { get; set; } = new HashSet<ObjectState>();

    public virtual ICollection<ObjectState> PreviousObjectStates { get; set; } = new HashSet<ObjectState>();

    public virtual ICollection<WorkflowEvent> WorkflowEvents { get; set; } = new HashSet<WorkflowEvent>();

    public virtual ICollection<WorkflowTransition> FromTransitions { get; set; } = new HashSet<WorkflowTransition>();

    public virtual ICollection<WorkflowTransition> ToTransitions { get; set; } = new HashSet<WorkflowTransition>();

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>An entity configuration class</summary>
internal class WorkflowConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Workflow>
{
    #region <Methods>

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Workflow> builder)
    {
        // NOTE: EF CORE Automatically Maps ALL Inherited Properties (by default)
        // ----------
        // PROPERTIES
        builder.ToTable(typeof(Workflow).Name, "component")
            .HasKey(m => m.Id)
            .HasName("PK_component.Workflow.Id");

        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(e => e.ContextTypeId)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(e => e.FullName)
            .HasMaxLength(300)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        // -------
        // INDEXES
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.ContextTypeId)
            .IsUnique(false)
            .HasDatabaseName("IX_component.Workflow.ContextTypeId");

        builder.HasIndex(e => e.FullName)
            .IsUnique(true)
            .HasDatabaseName("UX_component.Workflow.FullName");

        builder.HasIndex(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnique(false)
            .HasDatabaseName("IX_component.Workflow.Name");

        builder.HasIndex(e => e.Order)
            .IsUnique(false)
            .HasDatabaseName("IX_component.Workflow.Order");

        // -----------
        // CONSTRAINTS
        builder.HasOne(e => e.ContextType)
                .WithMany(e => e.Workflows)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ContextTypeId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_component.Workflow_component.ContextType.Id");
    }

    #endregion
}
```